# скрипт для закрытия iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Лендинг собран на конструкторе. Через вставку HTML-кода прописываю `iframe` без атрибутов, только переменная `name`. Стандартными инструментами конструктора при нажатии на ссылку запускается видео со стороннего ресурса в `iframe`.
Задача - после проигрывания видео дать пользователю возможность закрыть окно `iframe`.
В техподдержке написали, что это можно сделать, установив скрипт закрытия окна. Подскажите, плиз, что там писать.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
function closeIFrame(){
     $('#youriframeid').remove();
}
```

По совету @Mikl, если фрейм в дальнейшем еще будет использоваться, то нужно использовать метод `hide()`:

```
$('#youriframeid').hide();
```

Comment: Думаю, достаточно будет просто `$('#youriframeid').hide();` вдруг этот iframe будет использоваться еще раз.

Comment: @Mikl, да, как вариант.

Comment: `display: none;`, действительно, поможет. Но что делать, если где-то крутиться скрипт, который работает с этим элементом? Его же сначала надо остановить, а то ошибок кучу поймаешь.

Comment: Спасибо, коллеги! Пошел пробовать